# Is it possible using PHP and HTML to download an entire folder and its contents, WITHOUT zipping the folder?

Tags: php, directory, download

I have a folder on a website, that I need to be made available for download.

In a perfect world, I'd like to download the file, and all of its contents as is, unzipped. UNZIPPED is the keyword here.

I already have a working solution downloading the folder, as a ZIPPED folder, however my client is requesting that the folder remains unzipped.

Is this possible to do, using PHP and HTML, and is there any potential security risks involved with specifying a plain folder to download?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, it's not possible to download the entire folder. Or it may be possible but such a mess-around to implement that zipping it would be much preferable.

Comment: You can use google drive. Your clients can easily download specific files from the drive folder. I think it's a Simple & better option!

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies, and clarification. It may be best just sticking to the Zipped Files.

Comment: As Awais has said, use Google Drive.  You are trying to reinvent the wheel.  You can also use Dropbox etc.  You could paste the link onto your website if you really wanted.